# How use nested model methods to set users into right and left?

Tags: laravel, tree, nested

Let me know how can I use nested model correctly .
I checked [nested package](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset).
I noted its methods how to root how to move etc.

I have a user table

[image]

that created for new user registeration under referral link of sponsor user.After that I want to set this users into right and left side of sponsor user,This mean binary tree. Sponsor user who own referral link can set new users into right and left side of him.For that I want to create next table to store right and left side data for users.So I check nested model package.But I not clear how to use it.I mean by using this nested methods ,user data can insert automatically into right and left side column of tree table.And then view by blade template.Or not

tree table is as follow

```
Schema::create('trees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        NestedSet::columns($table);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

If not Please guide me the correct flow that suitable for my project.

Thanks

Comment: Lets start from the top: what do you mean by "I cannot forward due to this problem"?

Comment: I mean I not clear how to use this nested model to faciliatate with my create.So plz show flow

Comment: I don't want to "show flow" if I have no clue what your question is

Comment: I have a user table that created for new user registeration under referral link of sponsor user.After that I want to set this users into right and left side of sponsor user,This mean binary tree. Sponsor user who own referral link can set new users into right and left side of him.For that I want to create next table to store right and left side data for users.So I check nested model package.But I not clear how to use it.I mean by using this nested methods ,user data can insert automatically into right and left side column of tree table.And then view by blade template.Or not .

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information

Comment: Hello I edited the question.Do you get the point?

Comment: why noone can answer my question